# Merging streams when _any_ of the substreams has a value ready

Tags: akka-stream, low-latency

From Akka-stream documentation, it looks like that all stream merging options (merge, mergeSorted, mergePreferred, zipN, zipWithN) work by waiting when all merged streams have the new element ready, then applying the merge strategy (combining elements into a tuple, or applying zip function, etc.)

This works well for offline processing (e.g. reading the data from files or HTTP and combining it), but it introduces latency in online processing. I need to merge streams of data produced by e.g. multiple Websocket connection, and deliver updates in the merged stream as soon as any of the source streams produces a value. Example: if there are source streams A and B, here's what should be in the merged stream:

Output stream starts with some initial value, e.g. `(None, None)`.

```
(A:1) (B:<not ready>) -> (Some(1), None)
(A:2) (B:<not ready>) -> (Some(2), None)
(A:3) (B:1)           -> (Some(3), Some(1))
(A:3) (B:2)           -> (Some(3), Some(2))
```

etc. Again, a new value appears in the output stream when *any* of the source stream produces a value, immediately.

Is there any combinator to achieve that?

Comment: > by waiting when all merged streams have the new element ready - this doesn't seem to be true. See, for example, the [Merge](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Merge) documentation page. It clearly defines that it "emits when **one** of the inputs has an element available" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `Merge` and `MergePreferred` stages do emit elements downstream even if not all upstreams have an element available.

From your example it looks like you are looking for zipping sources though. And yes, `Zip` emits the zipped tuple downstream only when it has elements to zip from all its upstreams. To overcome this you can 'lift' your sources to produce `Option`s, and make them emit `None` whenever there is nothing else to emit. The source wrapper can look like this:

```
  def asOption[In, Mat](source: Source[In, Mat]): Source[Option[In], Mat] =
    Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(source.map(Option(_))) {
      implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[Mat] => src =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val noneSource = Source.repeat(None)
      val merge = builder.add(MergePreferred[Option[In]](1))

      src        ~> merge.preferred
      noneSource ~> merge.in(0)

      SourceShape(merge.out)
    })
```

At this point you can zip your sources as you would normally.

```
  val src1: Source[Int, NotUsed] = ???
  val src2: Source[Int, NotUsed] = ???

  val zipped = asOption(src1) zip asOption(src2)
```